# Initialize static members in PHP

Tags: php, static-members

```
class Person {
  public static function ShowQualification() {
  }
}

class School {
  public static $Headmaster = new Person(); // NetBeans complains about this line
}
```

Why is this not possible?

I want to be able to use this like

```
School::Headmaster::ShowQualification();
```

..without instantiating any class. How can I do it?

**Update:** Okay I understood the WHY part. Can someone explain the HOW part? Thanks :)

Comment: Static properties are also called class properties in opposite to object properties. Why would you want to have only *one* headmaster for *all* schools?

Comment: Please don't look at it semantically. I cannot post my proprietary code. I just thought up some stupid example. Might as well have named them abc and xyz :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php),

> "Like any other PHP static variable,
>   static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or
>   constant; expressions are not
>   allowed."

`new Person()` is not a literal or a constant, so this won't work.

You can use a work-around:

```
class School {
  public static $Headmaster;
}

School::$Headmaster = new Person();
```

Comment: Your answer being quoted, I understand the "why" part. But *how* should I modify my code so that I can use the classes as described?

Comment: +1 Thanks :).. Just out of curiosity, how do people live with this? PHP being a widely used language for web development, I am surprised we have to do it this way...

Comment: @Senthil: Because it's not the end of the world and it's very little effort?

Answer (score -2):

`new Person()` is an operation, not a value.

> Like any other PHP static variable,
>   static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or
>   constant; expressions are not allowed.
>   So while you may initialize a static
>   property to an integer or array (for
>   instance), you may not initialize it
>   to another variable, to a function
>   return value, or to an object.

http://php.net/static

You can initialise the School class to an object:

```
class School {
  public static $Headmaster; // NetBeans complains about this line
  public function __construct() {
    $this->Headmaster = new Person();
  }
}

$school = new School();
$school->Headmaster->ShowQualification();
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to instantiate. I just want to use them like Class1::Member1::SubMember.

Comment: You can't use $this for a static variable and it doesn't make any sense instantiating an object to access a static variable.